# VSCode Python Interpreter not updating automatically

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As the titles implies, VSCode is not updating the Interpreter to the correct one. Do mind that version 3.8.5 is not even present in my system anymore. Also the virtual environment is created with Python's `venv` instead of poetry.

[image]

The only thing that fixes the problem is a fresh installation of VSCode. I use a portable mode if that's something worth mentioning.

It's annoying to create a fresh installation and update my settings every time I happen to change between python versions.

If someone has an idea on how to fix the problem I'd would highly appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a .vscode/settings.json on your workspace? Your workspace or folder settings usually stores the path to your python interpreter (the one displayed at the bottom left), if you [selected an environment for your workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: it is controlled by a setting, global or workspace, if the setting is defined VSC DOES NOT look if there is a different one and use it. I have 3 global python interpreters and 3 venv environments in the workspace. If I want to use a particular environment I change the one to use, If I select the wrong one VSC generates some error. So use the command `Select Python Interpreter`. You most likely install a new python version every day or multiple times a day.

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes I do and it points to the `.venv` file, which points to the corresponding Python version (3.9.6 in this case). It's clearly a VSCode cache problem. By any chance you know in which file it stores those info?

Comment: @rioV8 I don't install different Python versions frequently but I do change between versions since I am testing compatibility of some applications. And yes, I do try to change my interpreter using cmd `Select Python Interpreter` but for some reason it caches the `.venv` one and it does not change it back.

By any chance you are aware of the file that keeps that setting so I can force refresh it by deleting it? Also do you VSCode's portable mode? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a workspace open I assume? It is stored in the file `.vscode/settings.json` setting `"python.pythonPath"`. Tried with switching interpreters and best practice is: **If you switch interpreter delete all your Python Debug Console terminals**. Install is not needed, just try a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem because I have multiple .venvs in same workspace. My workaround is to

- copy the full python path you want to point to
- run cmd `Select Python Interpreter`
- click `Set At Workspace Level`
- click `+ Enter Interpreter Path`.
- Copy and paste the path.

Works for me.